# ERROR Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion IONIC, recibiendo data de un arduino por bluetooth y mostrando esa data en pantalla a traves de un radial-gauge canvas.
He dibujado el radial-gauge en mi page home y cuando le doy ng serve al proyecto para verlo por web, no hay ningun problema; sin embargo, cuando hago **ionic cap copy android --prod** me arroja el sgte error:

```
Error: src/app/home/home.page.html:17:17 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

17                 value="80"
```

Mi home.html es:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <radial-gauge width="200" 
                height="200" 
                units="Km/h" 
                title="false" 
                value="80"
                min-value="0" 
                max-value="220" 
                major-ticks="0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220"
                minor-ticks="2" 
                stroke-ticks="false" 
                highlights='[
                      { "from": 0, "to": 50, "color": "rgba(0,255,0,.15)" },
                      { "from": 50, "to": 100, "color": "rgba(255,255,0,.15)" },
                      { "from": 100, "to": 150, "color": "rgba(255,30,0,.25)" },
                      { "from": 150, "to": 200, "color": "rgba(255,0,225,.25)" },
                      { "from": 200, "to": 220, "color": "rgba(0,0,255,.25)" }
                      ]' 
                color-plate="#222" 
                color-major-ticks="#f5f5f5" 
                color-minor-ticks="#ddd" 
                color-title="#fff"
                color-units="#ccc" 
                color-numbers="#eee" 
                color-needle-start="rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)"
                color-needle-end="rgba(255, 160, 122, .9)" 
                value-box="true" 
                animation-rule="bounce"
                animation-duration="500" 
                font-value="Led" 
                animated-value="true"
                ></radial-gauge>

<ion-item>{{dataSevice.dataRecibida[0]}}</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Ya he intentado quitarle las comillas al valor y nada.
El error me sale cada que trato de asignar un valor al atributo value de la etiqueta radial-gauge y no se por qué.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: El componente `radial-gauge`, tiene alguna interfaz? Quizá en su tipado, sea number y no string, y al transpilar por eso bota el error

Comment: Si, es de tipo number..pero como declararía en el atributo el tipo number?

Answer (score 0):

Serviría que incluyeras que librería de charts estas usando para darle un vistazo y dar una respuesta más acertada, pero esta puede funcionar.

En tu archivo `.ts` del componente declara una variable de clase

```
radialGaugeValue: number = 80;
```

Y luego el atributo del chart lo manejas con Ionic para que puedas inyectarlo

```
<radial-gauge 
 [value]="radialGaugeValue" 
 ...
</radial-gauge>
```

La forma en la que Typescript está interpretando el valor, es que le estas pasando una cadena, seamos más explícitos en el tipado de datos.

**AGREGO**

También serviría si lo inyectas directo sin necesidad de usar el `.ts`

```
<radial-gauge 
 [value]="80" 
 ...
</radial-gauge>
```

Comment: Estoy usando Canvas-gauge https://canvas-gauges.com/. Ya intente hacer la forma en como lo explicas, si bien ya no me sale el error, la aguja del radial-gauge no actualiza valor.